# Does atomic variable's access after mutex need memory order?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I have 2 threads, one atomic variable A and a mutex L:

- thread 1:

```
void changeA(val)
{
  // Will monotonically increase A
  L.lock();
  int oldVal = A.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
  A.store(max(val, oldVal), std::memory_order_relaxed);
  // Do something
  ...
  L.unlock();
}
```

- thread 2:

```
bool waitUntilGreaterThan(int valB)
{
  L.lock();
  while (A.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) <= valB)
  {
    // do something 1
    L.unlock();
    // Do something 2
    ...
    L.lock();
  }
  L.unlock();

  // Do I need a memory barrier here?
  newVal = A.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
  ASSERT(newVal > valB);
}
```

My question is do I need to use memory barrier on last `load` line or `memory_barrier_relaxed` is sufficient? Since mutex should already implicitly issued a memory barrier.

**Update**: I updated the code sample, the actual purpose of last line is just for assertion that the waiting works and there is no accident value decrease (it will be removed in release build). Is there any possibility that compiler might re-order the last load to happen before the waiting loop on thread 2?

**Further info**: In my actual project, thread 1 is not one thread, it actually represents multiple threads in a thread pool controlled by an internal framework.
Pls ignore whether the sample code should be re-written in a better way or not. The question is about the behaviors of the code. In actual production code, there are more things than just `A`, and `A.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` is actually wrapped inside another function, for example `isResourceBusy(valB)`.

Comment: The default memory order is `seq_cst`, which is always safe but slow.  You can safely use `relaxed`, and it seems pointless to take and release the lock; that could happen right *before* `changeA()` runs, no guarantee of it being after.  Just use `A.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)`  (It's order, not barrier - you have a typo in your source).

Comment: Basically, **taking / releasing a lock every time you want to read A is totally defeating the purpose of using atomics**; you might as well just read it *inside* the critical section and make it non-atomic.  Or better, remove the locking and keep everything else the same.  If thread 1 is the only writer, it's safe to do a separate load and then store, without an atomic RMW.  (i.e. like you're doing, but not inside a critical section)

Comment: I updated the code to be more precise on what the waiting on thread 2 does

Comment: Now this deadlocks: your spin-wait loop is between `L.lock()` and `L.unlock()`, so changeA will be stuck forever, unable to modify A.  (Unless you remove the pointless locking).

Comment: Ok, now it's valid, although the locking is still doing nothing for you.  And you could just save the value you read inside the critical section, instead of doing another separate atomic load.  That could be different, although as long as it's monotonically increasing it can't violate the assert.  Generally it's a good habit to do `int tmp = A.load(mo_relaxed)` so you can keep using the same load result later, instead of loading it again.

Comment: Updated code again without deadlock. Could you post your full suggested code. I'm not sure what are you trying to say?

Comment: I'm saying your code would work just as well if you remove every like that contains `L.lock` or `unlock`, assuming only one thread ever calls `changeA`

Comment: OK, so you saying atomic alone with relaxed order can work too without mutex? Thanks. Actually my actual code is using mutex because it has to protect other things along side the variable `A`.

Comment: I asking if barrier is needed on last line since I'm confusing whether it might be possible that compiler may re-order my last load to happen before the waiting loop.

Comment: Furthermore, in my actual code, the `changeA` is not actually called by one thread. It is a callback that is invoked by multiple threads controlled by an internal framework.

Comment: re: update: no, operations from the same thread on the *same* atomic object are ordered wrt. each other.  You don't need an `atomic_thread_fence` (or `memory_order_acquire` in the loop).   But it's silly to do a separate load after the loop; just capture the loop loads with `while ( (tmp=A.load(relaxed)) <= valB ) { ... }` or whatever so you already have a value you know is high enough.

Comment: If `changeA` can be called by multiple threads, probably still avoid locking even for writers by using a `compare_exchange_weak` retry loop to synthesize an atomic max RMW operation.  Either way the reader certainly doesn't need to do locking; the only thing you need to avoid is one writer decreasing the value, e.g. if a small increase and a large increase try to update simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will keep them in mind. As mentioned, in actual code, there are more things to protect than `A`, there is a queue that contains pending operations needs to be done on `A`, etc. And the last assert is to making sure there is no unexpected loop breaking, or accident value decrease happened. In release build. the assert is removed eventually.
But I think I have the answer I looked for (which is the behavior of last load), thanks.